# Finding synonyms in DFS

Tags: dfs

Giving a path to a file on the network, for example:

```
\\server1\folder\file
```

I'm trying to find all the other paths (in my network) pointing to the exactly same file (not a copy of it, but a replicate or another mapping of it):

```
\\server2\folder2\file, \\server3\folder3\file
```

As far as i understand, all the information required is stored in the domain's active directory - i'm trying to figure out how to extract it, using a tool\script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with powershell with something like this :

```
$folders=get-dfsnfolder -path "\\your_dfs\path\*"
$points=foreach ($folder in $folders){get-dfsnfoldertarget -path $folder.path }

write-host $points
```